# Printer stops printing at page 138, every time.

Tags: windows-xp, laser-printer, lexmark-printer

I'm printing invoices from quickbooks premier 2009 and I have around 300 to print. But the job always fails at 138. It doesn't give any error messages, the print dialog box just disappears. and quickbooks acts like nothing was printed.

The printer is a lexmark color laser c544n on windows xp sp3. It's pretty new.

I've tried reinstalling the driver as well as change the way it spools (sending it directly to the printer). But nothing seems to work.

I don't know how big the file is. But they are all 1 page invoices. There's nothing about page 138 thats different from the others. How would you find out how big the file is? It says memory standard: 128mb memory maximum: 640mb.

I did talk to quickbooks support, and they say it's the printers problem.

Comment: How big is the file? How big is the printer's memory? What is on page 138 that is different than prior pages? Look at quickbooks support as well.

Comment: When the it stops printing at 138 the document size is 45mb

Comment: How is the printer connected to the computer?  USB?  Can you try connecting the printer to a different USB port?

Comment: The info you provide is not sufficient to help much in troubleshooting the problem, unless one resorts to semi-blind guess-work. -- I conclude that you are printing from an application called *'quickbooks'* (which is unknown to me). - (1) What internal file format does quickbooks use (unless that is a quickbooks-specific format)? - (2) What sort of driver are you using for your Lexmark printer (i.e. PCL or PostScript or...?)? - (3) Does the problem appear likewise with a **different** 300 page quickbook document? -  (4) Does the problem go away, if you only print the pagerange 137-139 ?

Comment: Semi-blind guess: It could be one of the following 2 things: (1) the printer receives all 300 pages, but when rendering them, some problem is triggered when processing page 138 which leads to abortion of the job at that page. - (2) There is a weird problem triggered when the driver processes page 138 so the driver only sends what's done so far to the printer. - (3) The printer receives all 300 pages, but while rendering them, memory is overflowing at page 138.  [One could narrow down which of these is it by attention to detail while observing what's happening when the job runs.]

Comment: Did you check if the problem goes away when putting more physical memory into the printer?

Comment: Can you try printing just page 138 (if Quickbooks allows you to do that), and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the memory setting (if there is one) in the Windows printer configuration matches the actual memory of the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in this situation I would probably try printing to a PDF printer then printing the PDF. That way you can create the batch of invoices once with QuickBooks then keep printing the PDF until you get it all. You can try printing 100 pages at a time, or printing all pages except page 138, and that might help figure out whether the problem is something about page 138 or if the printer driver just can't handle a 138 page job for some reason.

Some free PDF printers to try:

- [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/)
- [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/)
- [PDF995](http://www.pdf995.com/)